# d3.js: Access data nested 2 level down

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Data structure:

```
var data = [ 
   {name: "male",
   values: [
     { count: 12345,
       date: Date 2015-xxx,
       name: "male" },
     {...}
   ]
  },
  {name: "female",
   values: [
     { count: 6789,
       date: Date 2015-xxx,
       name: "female" },
     {...}
   ]
  }
]
```

The values that I want to access are data[a].values[b].count

The values are used to draw circles for my plot

code for circle plot:

```
focus.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return x(d.values[i].date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return y(d.values[i].count); })
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(d.values[i].name); })
```

The problem is that `i = 1` because of its position in the object.

What I want to do is to loop through all the `objects` under `values`. How can I do that?

Edit: I wish to learn how to do it without altering the data, to improve on my skills.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a lib like underscore.js to edit your data array.

From underscore docs:

> **flatten** _.flatten(array, [shallow]) 
>   Flattens a nested array (the nesting can be to any depth). If you pass shallow, >the array will only be flattened a single level.
>
> ```
> _.flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
> -> [1, 2, 3, 4];
>
> _.flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]], true);
> -> [1, 2, 3, [[4]]];
> ```
>
> **map** _.map(list, iteratee, [context]) Alias: collect 
>   Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a >transformation function (iteratee). The iteratee is passed three arguments: the >value, then the index (or key) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the >entire list.
>
> ```
> _.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
> => [3, 6, 9]
> _.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key){ return num * 3; });
> => [3, 6, 9]
> _.map([[1, 2], [3, 4]], _.first);
> => [1, 3]
> ```

[Underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten)

In your code you can do something like that:

```
var flatData = _.flatten(_.map(data, (d)=>d.values));
focus.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return y(d.count); })
    .attr("r", 4)
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(d.name); })
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but is it possible to do it with just pure JS or d3 without altering the data? I want to improve on my skills :)

Comment: @shawn Of course you can. Underscore.js is open source, you can check how things are done. It is not that hard to understand. Code here: http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js
You cannot easily do that with d3 without altering the data... There is a way, but it's not optimized. You quand do a foreach data, then do the focus.selectAll on values and append your circles that way.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do what you want using D3 only, without any other library and without altering the data. One of them is using `groups` to deal with "higher" levels of data (regarding the nested data). Let's see it in this code:

First, I mocked up a dataset just like yours:

```
var data = [ 
    {name: "male",
    values: [{ x: 123,y: 234},
        { x: 432,y: 221},
        { x: 199,y: 56}]
    },
    {name: "female",
    values: [{ x: 223,y: 111},
        { x: 67,y: 288},
        { x: 19, y: 387}]
    }
];
```

This is the data we're gonna use. I'm gonna make a scatter plot here (just as an example), so, let's set the domains for the scales accessing the second level of data (`x` and `y` inside `values`):

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([20, 380])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d3.max(d.values, function(d){
            return d.x;
        })
})]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([20, 380])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d3.max(d.values, function(d){
            return d.y;
        })
})]);
```

Now comes the most important part: we're gonna bind the data to "groups", not to the circle elements:

```
var circlesGroups = svg.selectAll(".circlesGroups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d){ return (d.name == "male") ? "blue" : "red"});
```

Once in the first level of data we have 2 objects, D3 will create 2 groups for us.

I also used the groups to set the colours of the circles: if `name` is "male", the circle is blue, otherwise it's red:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ return (d.name == "male") ? "blue" : "red"});
```

Now, with the groups created, we create circles according to the `values` in the data of each group, binding the data as follows:

```
    var circles = circlesGroups.selectAll(".circles")
        .data(function(d){ return d.values})
        .enter()
        .append("circle");
```

Here, `function(d){ return d.values}` will bind the data to the circles according to the objects inside `values` arrays.

And then you position your circles. This is the whole code, click "run code snippet" to see it:

```js
var data = [ 
    {name: "male",
    values: [{ x: 123,y: 234},
        { x: 432,y: 221},
        { x: 199,y: 56}]
    },
    {name: "female",
    values: [{ x: 223,y: 111},
        { x: 67,y: 288},
        { x: 19, y: 387}]
    }
];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([20, 380])
 .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
   return d3.max(d.values, function(d){
    return d.x;
  })
 })]);
  


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([20, 380])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
   return d3.max(d.values, function(d){
    return d.y;
  })
 })]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeInner(-360);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSizeInner(-360);

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,380)")
 .call(xAxis);
 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
 .call(yAxis);
 
var circlesGroups = svg.selectAll(".circlesGroups")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("g")
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return (d.name == "male") ? "blue" : "red"});
 
var circles = circlesGroups.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(function(d){ return d.values})
 .enter()
 .append("circle");
  
circles.attr("r", 10)
 .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d.x)})
 .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d.y)});
```

```css
.axis path, line{
 stroke: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```