# d3.js flattening nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multidimensional-array

I am very new to d3 and js in general. This is my first project.

I have a dataset with the following structure (after using d3.nest with an aggregation function):

```
[
    {
        key: 1,
        values: [
            {
                key: 'Tucson International',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : -2,
                    avg_dep_delay : -2,
                    coords : [489.4325699362896, 401.0612266917171]
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'Burbank-Glendale-Pasadena',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : -4.25,
                    avg_dep_delay : -3,
                    coords : [385.86516356833704, 366.2906768310514]
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'Another Airport',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : 5,
                    avg_dep_delay : 12,
                    coords : [325.86516356833704, 386.2906768310514]
                }
            }      
        ]
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        values: [
            {
                key: 'Tucson International',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : 3,
                    avg_dep_delay : -1,
                    coords : [489.4325699362896, 401.0612266917171]
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'General Mitchell International',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : 8.666,
                    avg_dep_delay : 1.3333,
                    coords : [811.193714171889, 209.73464395018792]
                }
            },
            {
                key: '...',
                values: {
                    avg_arr_delay : 1,
                    avg_dep_delay  : 1,
                    coords : [111.111, 222.222]
                }
            }        
        ]
    }, 
]
```

I want to use the data to plot circles in a map with `cx=coords[0]`, `cy=coords[1]` and `r=avg_dep_delay`

I tried accessing it with the following code but failed. I only get one circle drawn.

```
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class','bubble')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nested)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i) {
        return d.values[i].values.origin_coords[0]; 
        })
    .attr('cy', function(d,i) {
        return d.values[i].values.origin_coords[1]; 
        })
    .attr('r',5)
    .attr('class','dest_circle');
```

I would like to change the data to the shape below to make it work.

```
[
    {
        Month: 1, 
        Airport: 'Tucson International', 
        avg_arr_delay : -2,  
        avg_dep_delay : -2, 
        coords : [489.4325699362896, 401.0612266917171]
    },
    {
        Month: 1, 
        Airport: 'Burbank-Glendale-Pasadena', 
        avg_arr_delay : -4.25,  
        avg_dep_delay : -3, 
        coords : [385.86516356833704, 366.2906768310514]
    },
    {
        Month: 1, 
        Airport: 'Another airport', 
        avg_arr_delay : 5,  
        avg_dep_delay : 12, 
        coords : [325.86516356833704, 386.2906768310514]
    },
    {
        Month: 2, 
        Airport: 'Tucson International', 
        avg_arr_delay : 3,  
        avg_dep_delay : -1, 
        coords : [489.4325699362896, 401.0612266917171]
    },
    {
        Month: 2, 
        Airport: 'General Mitchell International', 
        avg_arr_delay : 8.666,  
        avg_dep_delay : 1.333, 
        coords : [811.193714171889, 209.73464395018792]
    },
    {
        Month: 1, 
        Airport: '...', 
        avg_arr_delay : 1,  
        avg_dep_delay : 1, 
        coords : [111.111, 222.222]
    }
]
```

I found the following post that has appears to be a similar problem but wasn't able to get it to work [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059870/d3-js-access-data-nested-2-level-down).

Comment: How can your `nest` data have 2 `key:'5'` values? The `values` are `Array`s not objects. Have you looked at Gerardo's answer to the SO link you give?

Comment: @rioV8 - I did, however when using the `_flatten `, the data would not flatten to the format and the d3 object does not seem to be able to access it.

Comment: Not `rm4` answer, Gerardo does **not** use flatten. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061141/9938317